# What can I substitute for pineapple in punch?

Tags: substitutions, drinks, pineapple

I want to make St. Cecilia's Punch, which calls for 1/2 small pineapple.  My friend has a pineapple allergy and I need a suggestions as to what I can replace the pineapple with in this recipe.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide the full recipe for context, although i suspect in most punch recipes you can simply omit it.

Answer (score 3):

If this [recipe from Fine Cooking](http://www.finecooking.com/drink-recipes/st-cecilia-society-punch.aspx) is typical, it looks like pineapple is as much garnish as flavor.

The things it adds to the punch are:

- Fruitiness with a complex floral quality
- A somewhat tropical feeling
- Some acidity

I would suggest trying instead some mango, with extra lemon juice to compensate for the acidity.

Another choice might be really nice red grapefruit supremes.

Comment: My first thought was mango, but that doesn't cut into chunks so nicely as pineapple. Maybe half orange segments (no peel) from a small variety, such as blood orange?http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_orange Kiwi could work except green.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger I like to think mango makes up in flavor what it lacks in appearance. :-)